Residue's theorem- analytic continuation

Let $U$ be an open set and  $A \subset U$ a finite set ; let $\gamma$ be a simple loop and  null homotopic in $U$ such that $tr(\gamma) \cap A= \varnothing$.
Let $f: U -A \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function; then
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} f = \sum_{c \in A \cap int({\gamma})} res(c,f)$$

Let $A \cap int({\gamma})=\{z_1, \dots, z_k\}$; near $z_k$; $f(z)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n;z_k}(z-z_k)^n$
Let $f_k(z)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_{n;z_k}(z-z_k)^n$ and then, we have $F(z)=f(z)-f_{i}(z)$ is analytic near $z_i$ and we could consider $F(z_0)=a_{0,z_i}$ to obtain an analytic continuation of $F$ to $z_i$, but could we say that $f(z) - \sum_{i=1}^{k}f_i(z)$ admits an analytic continuation over $U$?

Observe that each $f_i$ is analytic at other points different from $z_i$. Therefore $f-\sum_i f_i$ is a sum of analytic functions at points other than the $z_i$.
